# Undefined Behavior: A checklist for code reviews

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are all the common undefined behaviour that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-abo)

I am about to prepare a checklist or guideliness for C++ self & peer code reviews, Since there are so many scenarios which may lead to realm of the dreaded `Undefined Behavior`, I was thinking of coming up with a sort of checklist of Undefined behaviors in most heavily used C++ language constructs.

Ofcourse it is not possible to anticipate the Undefined behaviors which emnate through modifications of variables between `Sequence points` but I think it is possible to list down scenarios emnating from other scenarios.

***If you were performing a code review what commonly `Undefined Behavior` producing scenarios would you look out for?***

Comment: It's a half hour job to search the standard for *all* mentions of undefined behaviour and list the potential causes... (I've included such a list in one of my old S.O. answers).  If you're serious about this you'll want such an exhaustive list and not an ad-hoc off-the-top-of-our-head collection from S.O. readers.  Given such a list, you're in a better position than us to say which ones you think are worth checking for given your coding environment, techniques and robustness needs....

Comment: @Tony: I could'nt find any duplicate, Eventhough I explicitly searched for it. Can you post a link to your previous answer?

Comment: I couldn't find mine (maybe the question went in S.O. housekeeping), but Greg's link looks spot on.

Comment: @Tony, @Greg Hwegill: Thanks! voting for closing this one.

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Bad `delete`

```
T* p = new T[N];
delete p; // ...1
delete (p+x); //...2
```

**(2)** Missing `return`

```
int* foo ()
{
  // code
  return p;
  // code
}
```

**(3)** Double `delete`

**(4)** Reference to temporary

**(5)**  Adding `vector` element to itself (when size was defined)

```
  vector<int> vi(1);
  vi.push_back(0);
  vi.push_back(vi[0]); // it can become a use case of pt(4) (sometimes)
```

Answer (score 1):

deleting only pointers that are newed. for example, you can't call `p = new int [5];` and then `delete p+2;` this may cause undefined behavior.

also when trying to use dlls only use primitive types since different compilers create different memory layout and that may cause some problems if you try to exchange classes or structs.

the other thing that I can think of is to watch out for the deleted memory, in some cases, you can write and read from those places without any error or access violation but it's always undefined behavior.

Comment: You can't even `delete p;` in this case. You must `delete [] p;` or it's undefined behavior.

Comment: @fred larson that thing depends on compiler, in some compilers there is no defrence between `delete p` and `delete  []p`

Comment: One of the amazing things about undefined behavior is that, under certain compilers/circumstances, it might appear well defined.

Comment: @dennis: agreed but the sad point is even on same compiler your code might not work if you just add something in some other file in some other class which is absolutly not related to your ***misbehaved*** code!

Answer (score 1):

Non-Availability of Virtual Destructor in polymorphic base class

Trivial Example

```
class Base
{
   public:
    Base();
   // some virtual functions     
   // no virtual destructor
   ~Base();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   public:
   Derived();
   // override the functions here      
   ~Derived();
};
// definitions
int main()
{
   Base *p = new Derived();
   // function calls
   delete p; // UB
}
```

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-abo/367662#367662) is a comprehensive list of  undefined behaviour scenarios in C++.

Comment: This is not necessarily UB; it can cause bad effects. http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#virtual-dtor

Comment: @iammilind : It is **definitely** UB. $5.3.5/3 In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the
  static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the **static type shall have a virtual
  destructor or the behavior is undefined**.

Comment: @iammilind: Prof. Stroustrup has a nicely (apparently confusingly) understated way of expressing it, but his answer agrees with the Standard as quoted by Prasoon.

Comment: Yes, standard should be the correct resort. Bjarne has really understated the impact.

Comment: @Parasoon: Note that if the class is not intended to be used polymorphic (e.g. a mixin), then a `protected` destructor is fine too.

Comment: Also note that you don't need virtual destructors even for polymorphic use if you use shared_ptr (which you probably should).

Answer (score 1):

Less obvious cases than other answers:

- The initialization order of nonlocal statics in different translation units is undefined. That is:

a.cpp

```
struct SomeStatic
{
    SomeStatic()
    {
        // Some init code
    }
    void AMethodUsingTheInitdCode()
    {
        //Blah blah
    }
} static;
```

b.cpp

```
struct SomeStatic;
extern SomeStatic static;

struct SomeOtherStatic
{
    SomeOtherStatic()
    {
        static.AMethodUsingTheInitdCode(); //Undefined -- SomeStatic's init code may not have run yet.
    }
} runMe;
```